# How to correctly work with a class passed to a generic interface in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have an interface BetterEnum<T: Enum>. I need all my enum classes that will implement this interface to have multiple static methods. It would be logical to put these methods in the interface, but I don't know how

I tried putting the methods in the companion object and adding the @JvmStatic annotation, but IDEA requires me to specify the implementation of these methods. I'm fine with this, but for the methods to work I need to get a list of constants from the passed class T. I've tried calling methods directly from T, tried calling methods from this (but this is defined as an instance, not a class, apparently), tried calling from (T as Enum). I would be grateful for your help!

```
interface BetterEnum<T: Enum<T>> {
    companion object {
        //getting the first element of an enumeration list (for example)
        @JvmStatic
        fun <T : Enum<T>> test(): Enum<T> {
            //return T.values()[0] - does not work
            //return this.values()[0] - does not work
            //return (T as Enum<T>).values()[0] - does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You cannot do this. `test` cannot differentiate between `EnumA.test()` and `EnumB.test()` or even `BetterEnum.test()`. What does `test` even do in the last case? You cannot get "which enum is `test` called on" in `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin restricts such constructs (implicitly inheriting static methods) by design.

You can reproduce it by explicitly extending companion object from a shared implementation.

Note that operating on "unspecified" enum classes and type arguments make initializing such objects a bit complicated and not runtime safe.

Personally I wouldn't do it and design another solution, but for your curiousity:

```
abstract class BetterEnum<T : Enum<T>>(val clazz : Class<T>) {
    fun test(): Enum<T> {
        return clazz.enumConstants[0]
    }
}

enum class FooEnum {
    enumValue;

    companion object : BetterEnum<FooEnum>(FooEnum::class.java)
}

fun run() {
    FooEnum.test()  // works and returns enumValue
}
```